Purpose of periphrasis in Salman Rushdie's "Shalimar the Clown"
In Salman Rushdie's novel Shalimar the Clown (2005), I find a passage, quoted below, consisting almost entirely of periphrasis. The background to the passage is that the character Hasina runs a common television room (thus charging the visitors a small sum for each visit) in a terrorism-affected Kashmir valley, and on pages 284-285, the waza of Shirmal says this, to justify the closing of Hasina's business to avoid the terrorists' wrath:

"In that case," he said, "can't we just just tell our Hindu brothers and sisters that in response to the LeP intervention, and having regard to the gravity of the regional situation and having weighed the available options and only for the time being and in this dangerous climate and until things blow over and for their own good as well as ours and purely as a precautionary measure and without meaning anything bad by it and taking everything into consideration and in spite of our deep reluctance and with a heavy heart and while fully appreciating their very understandable feelings of disappointment and hoping earnestly for better days to come soon and with the intention of reversing the decision at the earliest feasible opportunity, it might be better for all concerned if." He stopped talking because he could not say the words aloud.

(LeP = "Lashkar-e-Pak or Army of the Pure", page 277.)
This periphrasis, this beating around the bush, how does the majority interpret it? Is the passage from Shalimar the Clown a feather in the writer's cap or wasting reader's time?

@GarethRees Totally agree with you. It simply doesn't help at all by downvoting without explanation. And if the question is "opinion-based", the downvoting is much more opinion-based - which is allowed though.

@Saravana didn't downvote, but maybe those who did found it obvious that the convoluted monologue is an intentionally comical effect to show the waza's embarrassment?

@guillaume31 That would make a good answer. Just because it's obvious to you doesn't mean it is obvious to the OP.

It's worth reminding those who've earned the privilege of downvotes that greater judgement needs to be exercised when the OP is a new contributor. By all means vote to close a question if it doesn't meet requirements: the "close" reasons give the OP an opportunity to edit the post to fix the problem(s). But drive-by downvotes are particularly hurtful to newcomers – some of us oldtimers can recall the punishing DVs we received when we started, back before there was a "be nice to new users" policy. :-)

@SilentSojourner – absolutely. And our LitSE site often welcomes opinion, as it's the very basis of literary criticism. Sure, we want an answer to be well-argued, preferably supported by evidence from the text or from other works or sources – but there are plenty of upvoted answers with no such references, merely opinion, even if it's good, sensible opinion. Those quibbling about the OP's wording – e.g. "how does the majority interpret it?" (etc) instead of "what is the author trying to achieve?" forget that a good answer will inevitably address the "correct" question.

@GarethRees Thanks, I'll hazard an answer only if no one who has read the book does, because I haven't and could misinterpret the character's intentions. It's also a sensitive subject that deserves educated answers not just guesses.

@guillaume31 You may be able to see the context of this passage at the Internet Archive.
